# Open accordion-menu on demand

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using this accordion-menu on this site here:
http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/killer-exhibitions-berlin-ii/

Now I'M working on some php-lines to open the specific tree, from the current post you're watching but I cant reach the accordion to open! This is what I've tried to open something in this accordeon:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the API in a wrong way. The [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) says there is a method `activate` to open the accordion programatively. As a method you have to invoke it like that:

```
$(".selector").accordion("activate", 2);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! I'm already calling the accordion this way: http://pastebin.com/F4Q2zsZL . Is there a way to pair both?

Comment: What you are doing there is initializing the accordion. You can simply follow that up by opening the first (or second or whatever) tab you like like `$(".selector").accordion({ ... }).accordion("activate", 2)` or specify your `active` property in the initialization: `$(".selector").accordion({ active: 2 })`

Comment: Do you have an idea, why its still not workin? I implemented your code! Whats wrong with it? http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/icke-und-er/ (Line 257) or http://pastebin.com/tNL64i6A

Comment: Can not see anything wrong with it. Use a modern browser to be able to debug the stuff or ask someone for *local* help.